# specific control of PdfChunks in iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

It's a bit of a long shot that anyone here will be able to help, but I figured I'd ask.

Using iText we want to produce lines of chapters and page numbers like

```
Chapter something..................................20
Chapter something else..........................10520
```

Which is easily accomplished by

```
            Paragraph tocLine = new Paragraph();
            tocLine.add(new Phrase(title, Font));
            tocLine.add(new Chunk(new DottedLineSeparator()));
            tocLine.add(pageName);
            document.add(tocLine);
```

Great! everything works... except the company we send these to to print them extracts object by object, ignoring the correct pdf display rules (for some reason).  Resulting in the much less pretty

```
Chapter something20................................
Chapter something else10520.....................
```

on some level this make sense because all the line content is being embedded in 1 PdfChunk where the DottedLineSeparator reports no width.  I think the problem could be fixed if I could get the three parts to render as 3 PdfChunks each aware of their boundaries.  I can't find a good way to get that level of control.  Everything I've tried results in iText merging my chunks.  Any ideas?

Comment: *on some level this make sense* --- no, it doesn't. If that company ignores how PDFs are to be printed, you shouldn't ask them to print your PDFs. Furthermore, PdfChunks merely are helper objects when creating the PDF. They later on are not present as entity in their own rights.